# mysql order by showing least value on top

Tags: php, mysql

I have this mysql query  -

```
"SELECT SALARY FROM emp ORDER BY salary DESC"
```

which is showing the following result -

```
| Salary|
| 9000  |
| 15500 |
| 13500 |
| 12700 |
| 12000 |
| 11000 |
```

I just don't understand why it is showing 9000 on the top...I mean if i have already declares that the salary has to be ORDER BY in Descending order ....then why it is doing so!!! please somebody help me!!!!

I have also tried to do it in the ascending order but then it is showing the '9000' in the bottom

Comment: what is the data type of the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well look at the digits in the number, 9000 = 4 and all the rest are 5. that is the right order. The column isn't set as INT I bet

Comment: if the column is set to INT I bet it will be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Probably the data type for the field salary is incorrect.
Try to use DECIMAL(10,2) for example, or FLOAT.

MySQL thinks the salary is a STRING.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(SALARY AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS num FROM emp ORDER BY num DESC
```

Try this